what guitar VST and FX should I use to achieve a sound similar to "how u make me feel" by dj gummy bear
saw some similar questions get great answers here: I'm trying to figure out which guitar type / VST and FX would be needed to achieve a similar muted / reverbed electric guitar sound to that at the very beginning of "how u make me feel" by dj gummy bear. Appreciate any help!

You might get a better response if you provided a link to the audio or video at the correct timestamp for the effect you are interested in, as many folks will not have heard of a particular artist or song.
